# PHP array random with two Output

Tags: php, arrays, random

I would like to spend answer and questions in a random principle.
I have problems with the output.

can you help me?

```
<?  
$Expos['u1'][1]=('question 1') . ('answer 1');
$Expos['u1'][2]=('question 2') . ('answer 2');
$Expos['u1'][3]=('question 3') . ('answer 3');


$Expos['u2'][1]=('question 4') . ('answer 4');
$Expos['u2'][2]=('question 5') . ('answer 5');
$Expos['u2'][3]=('question 6') . ('answer 6');


function array_multi_rand($Zoo){
    $Boo=array_rand($Zoo);
    if(is_array($Zoo[$Boo])){
        return array_multi_rand($Zoo[$Boo]);
    }else{
        return $Zoo[$Boo];
    }
}

echo ('<h1>') . (array_multi_rand($Expos)) . ('</h1>'); /* QUESTION (how the write this part)*/
echo '<button class="show">Show Answer</button>';
echo ('<p>') . (array_multi_rand($Expos)) . ('</p>'); /* ANSWER (how the write this part)*/
?>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: What is the expected output? What are you getting instead of that? Please give some more details so that we can understand exactly what is going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add some special character between question and answer in your array that won't appear neither in question nor in the answer or create associative array.

Example with adding special character:

```
<?php
$Expos['u1'][1]=('question 1') . '#'. ('answer 1');
$Expos['u1'][2]=('question 2') . '#'. ('answer 2');
$Expos['u1'][3]=('question 3') . '#'. ('answer 3');


$Expos['u2'][1]=('question 4') . '#'. ('answer 4');
$Expos['u2'][2]=('question 5') . '#'. ('answer 5');
$Expos['u2'][3]=('question 6') . '#'. ('answer 6');


function array_multi_rand($Zoo){
    $Boo=array_rand($Zoo);
    if(is_array($Zoo[$Boo])){
        return array_multi_rand($Zoo[$Boo]);
    }else{
        return $Zoo[$Boo];
    }
}
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$selected = explode('#', array_multi_rand($Expos));



echo ('<h1>') . $selected[0] . ('</h1>'); 
echo '<button class="show">Show Answer</button>';
echo ('<p>') . $selected[1] . ('</p>'); 
?>
```

Example with multidimensional array (notice that function array_multi_rand was changed a bit):

```
<?php
$Expos['u1'][1]= array( 'q' => 'question 1', 'a' => 'answer 1');
$Expos['u1'][2]=array( 'q' => 'question 2', 'a' => 'answer 2');
$Expos['u1'][3]=array( 'q' => 'question 3', 'a' => 'answer 3');


$Expos['u2'][1]=array( 'q' => 'question 4', 'a' => 'answer 4');
$Expos['u2'][2]=array( 'q' => 'question 5', 'a' => 'answer 5');
$Expos['u2'][3]=array( 'q' => 'question 6', 'a' => 'answer 6');


function array_multi_rand($Zoo){
    $Boo=array_rand($Zoo);
    if(is_array($Zoo[$Boo]) && !isset($Zoo[$Boo]['q']) &&  !isset($Zoo[$Boo]['a'])){
        return array_multi_rand($Zoo[$Boo]);
    }else{
        return $Zoo[$Boo];
    }
}
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$selected =  array_multi_rand($Expos);



echo ('<h1>') . $selected['q'] . ('</h1>'); 
echo '<button class="show">Show Answer</button>';
echo ('<p>') . $selected['a'] . ('</p>'); 
?>
```